# REST: Get edit / update metadata url / numeric id by guid

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm creating a folder inside library via rest and as next step I search it again via

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{docLibraryName}')/Items?$filter=(OpportunityNumber eq '{folderName}')&$top=1
```

to get Edit url in a form

```
_api/Web/Lists(guid'293c51c7-0628-4fb4-85a4-8bc484efed86')/Items(128)
```

as only this url which has List guid and numeric ID of a folder allows me to do post to update its metadata.

problem is first query returns me guid (after placing index on it) of the folder and not numeric value

```
...<id>66c976c3-c1b1-4aa4-88c0-57e0c333052d</id>...
```

Is there a way to get numeric ID of a folder by its guid, or do the whole process in less steps, note I've tried

```
_api/Web/Lists(guid'07580897-2148-40a7-8464-87009e98183c')/GetItemByUniqueId(guid'66c976c3-c1b1-4aa4-88c0-57e0c333052d')
```

does not work and returns 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Comment: What is OpportunityNumber column here? You want item ID for a folder?

Answer (score 1):

To create a folder and get its ID in one request, you can simply create a list item with a folder content type (0x0120):

**POST request**

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Custom List')/items
```

**Body**

```
ContentTypeId: "0x0120"
Title: "FolderName"
__metadata: {type: "SP.Data.CustomListListItem"}
type: "SP.Data.TListItem"
```

**Response**

```
...
ID: 1
Id: 1
Title: "FolderName"
odata.id: "1c6a9c3a-2598-486a-8158-cf45d0503fd6"
...
```

Returned ID is the folder's item ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$select` parameter to select the folder `ID` like below:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,ID
```

This will return you the folder name & ID like:

```
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:FileLeafRef>folder2</d:FileLeafRef>
        <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">33</d:ID>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```

You can modify your REST call something like:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{docLibraryName}')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,ID,OpportunityNumber&$filter=(OpportunityNumber eq '{folderName}')&$top=1
```